# how to build an input-dropdownmenu using phonegap / cordova?

Tags: html, cordova

how can i implement an inputfield with a dropdown.. or a dropdown with an inputfield :D
it should be a normal dropdown when the user didnt type anything in the field and if he type in an "a" then the dropdown should only display the entries starting with an a..

is that even possible with phonegap? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) works nice on Android and iOS with Phonegap.

Comment: couldnt get this one working.. well.. i guess i did something wrong. but thanks, pal!